# Why do I have to refresh the page when I delete a post? MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I am a beginner in the MERN stack and I am interested in why I have to refresh the page after deleting the document (post)?

This is my Action.js

```
export const deletePost = id => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_POST_BEGIN });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.delete(`/api/v1/post/${id}`, config);

    dispatch({ type: DELETE_POST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_POST_FAIL,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg },
    });
  }
};
```

This is my Reducer.js

```
export const deletePostReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_POST_BEGIN:
      return { loading: true };
    case DELETE_POST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false };
    case DELETE_POST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload.msg };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And this is my Home page where i list all posts:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getPosts } from '../actions/postActions';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import Message from '../components/Message';
import Post from '../components/Post';

const HomePage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const allPosts = useSelector(state => state.getPosts);
  const { loading, error, posts } = allPosts;

  const deletePost = useSelector(state => state.deletePost);
  const { loading: loadingDelete } = deletePost;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {loading || loadingDelete ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Row>
            {posts.map(post => (
              <Col lg={4} key={post._id} className='mb-3'>
                <Post post={post} />
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

And this is my single Post component:

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const allPosts = useSelector(state => state.getPosts);
  const { loading, error, posts } = allPosts;

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const handleDelete = id => {
    dispatch(deletePost(id));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{post.author.username}</div>
      <Card>
        <Card.Img variant='top' />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{post.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{post.content}</Card.Text>
          <Button variant='primary'>Read more</Button>
          {userInfo?.user._id == post.author._id && (
            <Button variant='danger' onClick={() => handleDelete(post._id)}>
              Delete
            </Button>
          )}
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};
```

And my controller:

```
const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const postId = req.params.id;
  const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: postId });

  if (!post.author.equals(req.user.userId)) {
    throw new BadRequestError('You have no permission to do that');
  }

  await Post.deleteOne(post);

  res.status(StatusCodes.NO_CONTENT).json({
    post,
  });
};
```

I wish someone could help me solve this problem, it is certainly something simple but I am a beginner and I am trying to understand.

Comment: `StatusCodes.NO_CONTENT` 

Comment: You need to probably use the ```filter``` method to delete the post without reloading (like ```posts.filter(post => post.id !== id```), and at the same time delete the post in database

Comment: @Phil It's an npm package that describes the response number, it doesn't matter now :)

Comment: I brought it up because using `.json({ post })` certainly looks like content to me

Comment: @VersifiXion I know but I don't know where to filter. If you know or have time and if it's not difficult for you to write me the code where to put it to work :)

Comment: where do you store all the posts in Redux ?

Comment: @VersifiXion getPostsAction reducer -> export const getPostsReducer = (state = { posts: [] }, action)..... in state.posts array

Comment: since it's all about the posts, I would put everything in the same reducer, then you can do the filter method in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are not fetching the posts after delete is successful.

Try this inside the `HomePage` component:

```
...
const [isDeleting, setIsDeleting] = useState(false);
const { loading: loadingDelete, error: deleteError } = deletePost;

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!deleteError && isDeleting && !loadingDelete) {
        dispatch(getPosts());
    }
    setIsDeleting(loadingDelete);        
}, [dispatch, deleteError, isDeleting, loadingDelete]);
...
```

---

Another method is to use "filtering", but you have to update your reducer as such:

```
export const deletePostReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_POST_BEGIN:
      return { loading: true };
    case DELETE_POST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, data: action.payload}; // <-- this was changed
    case DELETE_POST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload.msg };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Now in your `HomePage` component, you will do something like this when rendering:

```
...
const { loading: loadingDelete, data: deletedPost } = deletePost;
...
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPosts());
  if (deletedPost) {
    console.log(deletedPost);
  }
}, [dispatch, deletedPost]);
  
return (
   ...
   <Row>
     {posts.filter(post => post._id !== deletedPost?._id).map(post => (
        <Col lg={4} key={post._id} className='mb-3'>
           <Post post={post} />
        </Col>
     ))}
   </Row>
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I'm going to try to understand why it's like this, I'm confused, I'm new to all this :)

Comment: @valkkorn see the updated answer for another method of accomplishing the same thing

Comment: The second method is better for me, but it doesn't work, I don't know what. When I delete a post and when I console.log (deletedPost); give me back undefined :/

Comment: @valkkorn try it now. I updated the reducer

Comment: Hmm same, i console.log(action.payload) and give me back <empty string>.. I don't understand why :/

Comment: @valkkorn if you put a `console.log(data)` after `await axios.delete...` in your `deletePost` function, does `data`  contain anything?

Comment: Yes, it returns my deleted post in console.log :)

Comment: Like this: Object { post: {…} }

Comment: If i set `posts.filter(post => post._id !== deletedPost?.post._id)` something strange happens, I delete one and remove it from my screen and then when I delete the other, the deleted one appears ..

Comment: @valkkorn yes I figured this was going on, I've updated the second method to also include some changes to your `useEffect`. Note: you must leave the `deletedPost` inside the dependency list of `useEffect`, even if you remove the console.log. This makes it so that you refetch the list of posts when one is deleted

Comment: Aahaha yees. Thank you man, this is so helpful :) useEffect always confuses me. Thank you once again, was fun debugging :)

Comment: @valkkorn welcome :)